# nginx-why my site not shown in Telegram and other messengers?

Tags: nginx

when i send my domain in a message in Telegram or other messenger apps, these apps, not shown mysite in telegram. i want to Telegram and other apps, show my site like below.

[image: why not shown my uploaded pic??]

i guess this problem is for webserver (nginx).
this is mysite's webserver setting:

```
server {
if ($blockedagent) {
    return 403;
}
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
    return 444;
}

client_max_body_size 20M;
listen 80;
server_name mysite.com wwww.mysite.com;


location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/my/myproject;
    expires 30d;
}    
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;
    return 301 $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri;
}
```

how can i solve this problem?
tanx

Comment: sorry men! i dont know why my picture not displayed!...this is in this linkhttp://uupload.ir/files/xfx9_untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about nginx settings. It's about your meta tags of the site. Go to your webpage and then see the source in the browser then check for meta title, description, og:image.

If you go to [authlab.io](https://authlab.io) see the source then you will get the idea.
The authlab.io shows the featured image, title and description in telegram and other messaging apps based on the meta tags.

[image: screenshot from Telegram]